# PySpark Builder Class vs builder method

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").appName("read-file-fit-model").getOrCreate()
```

The above code snippet works only when I am using `builder` attribute from SparkSession.

When I do the following:

```
spark = SparkSession.Builder.master("local[4]").appName("read-file-fit-model").getOrCreate()
```

It gives an error.

```
TypeError: master() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
```

When I use the `Builder` API like by initializing an instance of the `Builder` class, it works fine:

```
spark_sess = SparkSession.Builder()
spark_sess.master("local[4]").appName("read-file-fit-model").getOrCreate()
```

My question is:

Is there a difference between the two implementations and should one be preferred over another?

Answer (score 2):

Both implementations are identical to each other.

If you have a look at the source code, you can see that the `builder` attribute initialises the `Builder()` class.

From the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/session.py),

```
builder = Builder()
"""A class attribute having a :class:`Builder` to construct :class:`SparkSession` instances"""
```

So using, `SparkSession.builder` or `SparkSession.Builder()` would ultimately mean the same thing.